# Order topology neighborhood

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

I would like to know how we can describe the neighborhood of $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ in respect of $Z$ where $Z:=[0,1]^2\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ with a lexicographic order $(x,y)\le(x',y') \iff x<x'$ or $x=x',y\le y'$. I have no idea how in general describe neighborhoods for points $(x,y)\in Z$ with respect to the order topology, may you could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p=\langle a,b\rangle,q=\langle c,d\rangle\in[0,1]^2$, and let $\preceq$ be the lexicographic order on $Z=[0,1]^2$. You know that $p\preceq q$ if either $a<c$, or $a=c$ and $b\le d$. Clearly $\langle 0,0\rangle\preceq p\preceq\langle 1,1\rangle$ for all $p\in Z$, so $\langle Z,\preceq\rangle$ is a linear order with endpoints $\langle 0,0\rangle$ and $\langle 1,1\rangle$.

In general a basic open set in $Z$ is going to have the form $(p,q)$ for some $p,q\in Z$ with $p\prec q$, just as in $[0,1]$ most basic open sets have the form $(x,y)$ for some $x,y\in[0,1]$ with $x<y$. But just as in $[0,1]$, the endpoints require separate handling. A basic open neighborhood of $0$ in $[0,1]$ has the form $[0,x)$ for some $x\in(0,1]$, and similarly a basic open nbhd of $1$ in $[0,1]$ has the form $(x,1]$ for some $x\in[0,1)$. Basic open nbhds of the endpoints $\langle 0,0\rangle$ and $\langle 1,1\rangle$ of $Z$ are formed analogously: for each $p=\langle a,b\rangle\in Z\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ the left-closed, right-open interval

$$\begin{align*}
\Big[\langle 0,0\rangle,p\Big)&=\Big[\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle a,b\rangle\Big)\\
&=\big\{\langle x,y\rangle\in Z:\langle 0,0\rangle\preceq\langle x,y\rangle\prec\langle a,b\rangle\big\}
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

is a basic open nhbd of $\langle 0,0\rangle$. To see what this interval looks like, you should consider two cases separately, preferably making a sketch of each.

- If $a=0$, the point $p$ is on the $y$-axis, somewhere directly above the point $\langle 0,0\rangle$, and the set $(1)$ is a half-open vertical line segment lying on the $y$-axis: it’s $\{0\}\times[0,b)$.
- If $a>0$, the set $(1)$ consists of the entire rectangle $[0,a)\times[0,1]$ together with the half-open line segment $\{a\}\times[0,b)$ lying on the line $x=a$.

I’ll leave the basic open nbhds of $\langle 1,1\rangle$ to you.

**Added:** The situation at $\langle 1,1\rangle$ is the mirror image of that at $\langle 0,0\rangle$. If $p=\langle a,b\rangle\in Z\setminus\{\langle 1,1\rangle\}$, then the left-open, right-closed interval

$$\begin{align*}
\Big(p,\langle 1,1\rangle\Big]&=\Big(\langle a,b\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle\Big]\\
&=\big\{\langle x,y\rangle\in Z:\langle a,b\rangle\prec\langle x,y\rangle\preceq\langle 1,1\rangle\big\}
\end{align*}\tag{2}$$

is a basic open nbhd of $\langle 1,1\rangle$. If $a=1$, the point $p$ is on the line $x=1$ somewhere directly below $\langle 1,1\rangle$, and the interval is $\{1\}\times(b,1]$. If $a<1$, it contains all of the rectangle $(a,1]\times[0,1]$ and every point $\langle a,y\rangle$ with $b<y\le 1$, so it’s $$\Big(\{a\}\times(b,1]\Big)\cup\Big((a,1]\times[0,1]\Big)\;.$$ Since $(a,1]=\varnothing$ if $a=1$, we could actually just write

$$\Big(p,\langle 1,1\rangle\Big]=\Big(\{a\}\times(b,1]\Big)\cup\Big((a,1]\times[0,1]\Big)\;,$$

taking care of both cases at once. (You might try to do the same thing for the other endpoint.)

You work out basic open nbhds of other points in the same way, except that now you have to worry about what happens on both sides of the point, just as you do when you’re defining open nbhds in $[0,1]$ of points other than $0$ and $1$. Let $p=\langle a,0\rangle$, for instance, where $0<a\le 1$. Basic open nbhds of $p$ have the form $(q,r)$, where $q\prec p\prec r$. Suppose that $q=\langle b,c\rangle$ and $r=\langle d,e\rangle$. Then we must have $b<a$ (in order to have $q\prec p$), and we must have $a\le d$. Moreover, if $a=d$, then we must have $e>0$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
(q,r)&=\Big(\langle b,c\rangle,\langle d,e\rangle\Big)\\
&=\big\{\langle x,y\rangle:\langle b,c\rangle\prec\langle x,y\rangle\prec\langle d,e\rangle\big\}\\
&=\Big(\{b\}\times(c,1]\Big)\cup\Big((b,d)\times[0,1]\Big)\cup\Big(\{d\}\times[0,e)\Big)\;.
\end{align*}\tag{3}$$

(Note that if $a<d$ and $e=0$, then $[0,e)=\varnothing$, and the last term in that union is empty.)

Given the interval in $(3)$, we can always find $q\,'=\langle b\,',0\rangle$ and $r\,'=\langle a,e\,'\rangle$ such that $b<b\,'<a$, and either $0<e\,'<e$, or $d>a$ and $e\,'=1$. I leave it to you to check that $p\in(q\,',r\,')\subseteq(q,r)$, and

$$(q\,',r\,')=\Big((b\,',a)\times[0,1]\Big)\cup\Big(\{a\}\times[0,e\,')\Big)\;.$$

Draw some pictures to illustrate the various possibilities; this is very helpful in understanding the structure of the order. All other cases can be analyzed similarly.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. Secondly, why exactly do you use the notation $<>$ for elements in $Z$, is this simply to distinguish from the other intervals $()$ or is there a deeper meaning? Thirdly, in the two cases you consider in the end, why only for $a$ and not also for $b?$. Fourthly for $<1,1>$ I get $(<a,b>,<1,1>]$, but which cases do I need to consider now? Fifthly, what about $<x,0>$ and $<0,x>$, are these intervals special cases of the cases we already considered?

Comment: @Voyage: You’re welcome. I use $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ for ordered pairs; it’s *a* standard notation, and parentheses are already overworked, especially when you’re talking about intervals. I’m not sure what your third question is asking; it’s $a$ that determines the nature of the interval $(1)$. For four, the situation at $\langle 1,1\rangle$ is the mirror image of that at $\langle 0,0\rangle$, and once again the two cases depend only on the location of $a$. (I’ll say more if necessary, but it would be better if you could work it out from that.) I discussed only the endpoints because ...

Comment: ... you mentioned them explicitly in the question. A point $\langle x,0\rangle$ has a base of intervals of the form $$\Big(\langle a,0\rangle,\langle x,b\rangle\Big)\;,$$ where $0\le a<x$ and $0<b\le 1$. These aren’t the only open intervals containing $\langle x,0\rangle$, but every such open interval contains one of these. (By the way, the codes for the angle brackets are `\langle` and `\rangle`.)

Comment: Ok, in the case of $\langle 1,1\rangle$: 

$a=0: (0,b]\times \{1\}$

$a>0: (a,1]\times [0,1]$ together with $\{a\}\times (0,b]$   I do not know if these are correct. The last thing is if could explain the cases $\langle x,0\rangle$ and $\langle 0,x\rangle$ a little bit more in detail.

Comment: @Voyage: It was much too big for a comment, so I’ve expanded the answer.

Comment: @Voyage notice that Brian is using `\langle` + `\rangle` for the delimiters rather than `<` + `>`. The latter ones are only supposed to be used for less than and greater than.

Answer (score 0):

What is a basic open set in an order topology? When would such a set contain $(x,y)$?